# Solar Radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, thermal-radiation

If I have two container whit the same shape and thickness and both are made with PE (Polyethylene). These two containers are exposed to the same amount of solar radiation, but one is black and the other one is white. Which one will have the higher temperature inside of them and why? How do the radiation, convection, and conduction work in this example?

Comment: Not only the colour but also the "shinyness" (reflection) may be relevant here.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Are they filled with a fluid? Otherwise, I'm confused as to where the fluid dynamics tag is coming into play here...

Answer (score 1):

The black is hotter inside. The sun photons ( mainly the IR)  absorb in the black dye in the plastic, the photons move the electrons and cause molecule vibration which is heat!   Many IR photons are reflected off the white plastic into the ground or whereever.

The hot black plastic warms the air inside and outside of the bottle (conduction is result of molecules in contact). Air currents begin to flow which is called convection and these speed up the process of heat transfer (conduction) from plastic to air.